# how to catch mapped data with button clicks in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component created with react. I'm loading **JSON data** to fill a table and one column has a delete button. To delete u user, I need to get the **user id** after clicking on the button. I can load a delete button for each table row, but I can't get the user Id for each button click.

After loading the page, console is loading all the user ids at once without clicking the delete button. How can i get the user id for a particular user after clicking the delete button?

Component:

```
class EnhancedTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      userID: null
    };
    this.deleteUserById = this.deleteUserById.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    API.post("user/all", [], config).then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({
        data: data.response.data.map(user => (user.id, user.name, user.email))
      });
    });
  }

  deleteUserById(n) {
    console.log("user id", n);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TableBody>
        {data.map(n => {
          return (
            <>
              <TableCell>{n.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{n.email}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <DeleteIcon
                  onClick={this.deleteUserById(n.id)}
                  className="action"
                />
              </TableCell>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `this.deleteUserById` directly on render. You want to give the `onClick` prop a function that will be invoked when the event occurs instead.

```
<DeleteIcon onClick={() => this.deleteUserById(n.id)} className="action" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `this.deleteUserById(n.id)` in the onClick of the `DeleteIcon`, the function is called right then.
To avoid this, you can use `curried functions`.

You can modify your deleteUserById function to return a new function, like so:

```
deleteUserById = (n) => () => {
    console.log("user id", n);
}
```

This way, when you call the deleteUserById function in the onClick event, it will actually return a new function that would be triggered when the button is clicked:

```
<DeleteIcon
    onClick={this.deleteUserById(n.id)} // returns a new function. Does not console.log directly
    className="action"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also call *bind* on the function instead of the *arrow function*:

```
<DeleteIcon onClick={this.deleteUserById.bind(this, n.id)} className="action" />
```